# Error in google colabe! ValueError: No loss found. You may have forgotten to provide a `loss` argument in the `compile()` method

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm new to programming, I've literally just started learning right now and I'm doing it with various free tools, so I don't understand much about programming yet

I'm trying to write a neural network for self-learning

The meaning is as follows: I have 3 files. In the first (category) there is 1 column with 37 values and the column name is category

The second (ex) has 2 columns. The first column, called categ, contains 785 rows. The second column, called fix, contains 785 rows

In the third file (match), 1 column called match contains 3543 lines.

I need the match file to get a second column and add a value from the categ file based on data from the excel file to each of its values.

**At the moment, I have this code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.utils import pad_sequences
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, LSTM, Dense
from keras.models import Model

# Reading downloaded Excel files
# File with categories
from google.colab import files
upload = files.upload()
!ls
df_categories = pd.read_excel(open('categ.xlsx', 'rb'))
df_categories = pd.read_excel('categ.xlsx', index_col=None)
print(df_categories.columns)

# File with examples
from google.colab import files
upload = files.upload()
!ls
df_examples = pd.read_excel(open('ex.xlsx', 'rb'))
df_examples = pd.read_excel('ex.xlsx', index_col=None)
print(df_examples.columns)

# File with values for distribution
from google.colab import files
upload = files.upload()
!ls
df_to_distribute = pd.read_excel(open('match.xlsx', 'rb'))
df_to_distribute = pd.read_excel('match.xlsx', index_col=None)
print(df_to_distribute.columns)

# Data preprocessing

categories = df_categories['categ'].tolist()
values = df_examples['fix'].tolist()
to_distribute = df_to_distribute['match'].tolist()

categories = [str(category) for category in categories]
values = [str(value) for value in values]
to_distribute = [str(item) for item in to_distribute]

tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(categories + values + to_distribute)

tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(categories + values + to_distribute)
category_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(categories)
value_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(values)
to_distribute_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(to_distribute)

max_length = max(len(seq) for seq in category_sequences + value_sequences + to_distribute_sequences)
padded_category_sequences = pad_sequences(category_sequences, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
padded_value_sequences = pad_sequences(value_sequences, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
padded_to_distribute_sequences = pad_sequences(to_distribute_sequences, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')

# Creating a model
input_layer = Input(shape=(max_length,))
embedding_layer = Embedding(input_dim=len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1, output_dim=64)(input_layer)
lstm_layer = LSTM(64)(embedding_layer)
output_layer = Dense(36, activation='softmax')(lstm_layer)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Model training
#model.fit(padded_to_distribute_sequences, padded_category_sequences, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)
#model.fit(np.array(data_list), np.array(y), verbose=0, epochs=100)
model.fit(np.array(padded_to_distribute_sequences), np.array(padded_category_sequences), verbose=0, epochs=100)
```

**At the moment I'm getting the following error and I don't know how to fix it**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-4e982bc70a7f> in <cell line: 37>()
     35 #model.fit(padded_to_distribute_sequences, padded_category_sequences, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)
     36 #model.fit(np.array(data_list), np.array(y), verbose=0, epochs=100)
---> 37 model.fit(np.array(padded_to_distribute_sequences), np.array(padded_category_sequences), verbose=0, epochs=100)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/data_adapter.py in _check_data_cardinality(data)
   1958             )
   1959         msg += "Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples."
-> 1960         raise ValueError(msg)
   1961 
   1962 

ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 3549
  y sizes: 36
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of sample
```

I've tried changing lines of code based on recommendations from websites and forums, but it hasn't helped yet. I will be glad of your help!

I'm writing code in Google colab

Unfortunately, I cannot discard the original files that I use, since they contain personal data, but I can share a brief summary so that the logic of my actions is clear. I attach it at the end of the description

[an example of the files I use](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nEZbxzGnmRc3J8nmIOUwL0dE21sym5Lt)

Comment: Did you already debug the sizes of your arrays? You could use the debugger or just print them out. If you still can't find the issue, please share them with us. Please strip your code to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that doesn't need input files that you don't provide.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot discard the original files that I use, since they contain personal data, but I can share a brief summary so that the logic of my actions is clear. I attach it at the end of the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the target data `padded_category_sequences` and the input data `padded_to_distribute_sequences` have different numbers of samples, which causes a `ValueError`.

Add this after the "Data Processing":-

```
target_data = np.tile(padded_category_sequences, (len(padded_to_distribute_sequences) // len(padded_category_sequences), 1))
```

I am assuming that padded_category_sequences is your target data

Comment: I tried, but it turns out the following error :(but thanks for trying!

'ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 3549
  y sizes: 36
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.'

Comment: I just copied the data to align them, thanks, it helped!